# QML start Drag programmatically

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, drag

I'm currently stuck with Qts QML Drag and Drop system. What I'm trying to do is making drag and drop possible between windows, with the "classical" QML Drag and drop (i.e. by directly moving the QML component).

Since it seems to be impossible to do this directly, I am trying to archive this with a trick. I store the items data in a "global" location as soon as it gets dragged, and if it leaves the window, the item will delete itself. If the mouse now enters the same or another window, a new item will be created out of the globally stored data.

This all works so far, but of couse I want to "resume" the drag in the new window after the mouse entered it. And thats whats not working. Any ideas how this can be archived? Here my code for the DragItem:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 64
    height: 64

    readonly property alias dragActive: p.dragActive
    readonly property alias inFocus: p.isInParent

    function startDrag() {
        //If I enter the window, I will create the DragAngle object
        //and call this function to resume the drag
        console.log("startDrag");
        root.Drag.hotSpot = globalStore.hotSpot;
        //root.Drag.active = true;//didn't work either
        root.Drag.start();//this should work, but doesn't
    }

    QtObject {
        id: p
        property bool dragActive: false
        property point oldPos: Qt.point(0, 0);

        property bool isInParent: {
            if(root.x < (-root.width) ||
               root.y < (-root.height) ||
               root.x > root.parent.width ||
               root.y > root.parent.height)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        onIsInParentChanged: {
            //when the item leaves the visible area,
            //it destroys itself
            if(root.Drag.active)
                root.destroy();
        }
    }

    Drag.active: dragMouse.drag.active
    Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
    Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2
    Drag.keys: ["testkey"]

    Drag.onActiveChanged: {
        if(root.Drag.active) {
            p.oldPos.x = root.x;
            p.oldPos.y = root.y;
            root.Drag.hotSpot.x = dragMouse.mouseX;
            root.Drag.hotSpot.y = dragMouse.mouseY;
            p.dragActive = true;
            if(!globalStore.hasDrag)//store information globally (e.g. color)
                globalStore.startDrag(root.color, root.Drag.hotSpot);
        } else {
            p.dragActive = false;
            globalStore.endDrag();//reset global data, will not happen if destroyed
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: dragMouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        cursorShape: dragMouse.pressed ? Qt.DragMoveCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor

        drag.target: root

        onReleased: {
            if(p.dragActive && root.Drag.target) {
                root.Drag.drop();
            } else {
                root.x = p.oldPos.x;
                root.y = p.oldPos.y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have an idea how to start the drag or another way to accomplish drag and drop between windows, feel free to answere.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess the solution, if any, will be complicated. Why don't you re-design the application and implement a method to send or move the component between windows? I.e. `right click` -> `send to window A or B`. I think you can get the same goal but we need a simpler way.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to make it work if I "grab" the item by clicking it and release it on a second click. I would prefer "real" drag and drop, but if it's to complicated, I will do it this way.